# Why are Ubuntu related development questions closed?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions

I have had two different questions regarding the topic "Development on Ubuntu" (which is specifically mentioned as on-topic in the FAQ closed as off-topic.

The first one I happen to agree was better suited to Stack Overflow, however, my recent questions was Ubuntu specific, and absolutely belonged on this site.

I would like to know why my question was closed. Here is the link [to my question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198699/what-is-the-payout-date-for-commercial-applications)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*You asked **why** it was closed. Here's an attempt at answering that.*

People probably closed it as off-topic because they thought of it as not being about Ubuntu. It's also possible that they thought the question couldn't be answered here.

It is about Ubuntu, though I can see how a reasonable person could think otherwise. And it was answered--it has a well-sourced answer with two upvotes now. So I think it's good Oli reopened it.

Answer (score 4):

I've reopened it but this should be something that's easier to just talk to Canonical about. I suggest you just ping them a quick email now and you'll probably know before an answer is posted here.

Just make sure you answer your own question so that others learn from your experience.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do that. I planned on emailing them anyway, I just don't understand why it was closed.